# TLS connection to cloud mqtt for owntracks

Tags: ssl, mqtt

I want to establish a secure connection using TLS to m12.cloudmqtt.com (MQTT Cloud - cloudmqtt.com) for my owntracks MQTT client (Android device).

According to documentation at OWNTRACKS (http://owntracks.org/booklet/features/tls/ ) one has to provide CA CERT and the CLIENT CERT.

CA CERT I can understand according to documentation at cloudmqtt.com (www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-faq.html#TLS_SSL) is a trusted public CA. (That I can obtain from any cert store)

But for CLIENT CERT, how do I obtain this? Do I need to obtain a certificate ( for my android MQTT Client) from the above CA. Or is any other way possible to encrypt the session ?

Answer (score 0):

Client certificates are only needed if the broker supports certificate based client authentication. The connection will still be encrypted and you can verify the broker is who they claim to be.

The cloudmqtt [doc](https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-faq.html#TLS_SSL) does not mention certificate based client authentication. So the implication is that they do not support client authentication.

You should be able to set Owntracks up with a username and password and TLS without a client certificate

Comment: Can please elaborate on how can I secure my connection from OWNTRACKS to cloudmqtt using TLS because it requires CA CERT along with a CLIENT CERT in android app ?

Comment: The android client asks for the CA and Client Cert when you enable TLS, but they are not mandatory fields. You can just leave them blank

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Running the client without TLS ( I.e. with only username/ password authentication provided in mqtt ) is not a problem. I just wanted to add an extra security using encryption of data transmitted to and fro from client if possible ?

Comment: You can just enable TLS and leave to other bits empty, or you can encrypt the actual location info as mentioned in the doc

Comment: I tried the above method but it does not allow me to connect to my broker ( cloudmqtt.com ) without providing CA CERT and CLIENT CERT in OWNTRACKS and "disconnected with error".